# Issue on Custom backend Grid an Loader

Tags: grid, ajax

I have created a custom grid associated with a tab.

Now the grid work well, there is an issue with ajax call.

The  Ajax call hit the right url and the content is correctly displayed ( `onSuccess` state ) anyway for some reason the `onCompleate` state is never reached and so the loader continue to load.

The layout looks correct, I'm not sure what to check.

any suggestion ?

**Note:**
I think, I am correctly using the `getGridUrl()` function in the tab since the grid content, on the ajax call, is retrieved and delivered on the page ...

Comment: what code you have try please update

Comment: I found out ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General Debug with Ajax and Grid:**
The fact that the `onComplete` state is not hit point out that there is some error triggered by the js.
In the backend the ajax loader is managed by the js `varienLoader` class ( file `loader.js` ), in particular you may want to look into the `respondToReadyState` method.

**My issue:**
After some investigation I found out `respondToReadyState` (`loader.js`) was catching an exception *Cannot read the property down of null*
The exception what triggered by `bindFieldsChange` method (`grid.js`) and the reason was that the grid Id of the ajax call was different from the expected one.

I was not able to understand the exact reason because of this, anyway the solution for me was to change the tab class:
-> before I was extending directly the grid class
-> now I'm extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget`

Comment: For future readers, the answer here doesn't go deep enough to solve the issue. Depending on your implementation, when using as an AJAX-based grid, you should set the `id` property of the grid block within the constructor; eg: `$this->setId('grid_block_id');` The reason for JS failure as noted above is caused by a mismatched ID; that, when not explicitly set on a grid block, it will be autogenerated via `uniqid`. See parent method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget::getId`. The binding JS will now be able to locate your table on reload.

Comment: Feel free to improve the answer ...